# How to present an output without waiting for the rest of the script to run in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that should calculate a value, present it and then use the same value for further more expensive computation. The problem is that it shows me the output only after it finishes evaluating the whole script. Here is a simple example:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text_in","Enter text here",value = "This is text to process"),
      actionButton("go", "Go")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("first_text"),
      textOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

num_letter<-eventReactive(input$go, {
  nchar(input$text_in)})
output$first_text <- renderText(num_letter())

sec_calculation<-eventReactive(num_letter(), {
  Sys.sleep(3)
  num_letter()*num_letter()})
output$first_text <- renderText(num_letter())
output$results <- renderText(sec_calculation())


 }
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I added the `Sys.sleep` so it will be easier to see the problem. I would like to get the first output without waiting for the second one.

Comment: An easy solution would be to trigger the expensive computation by an action button.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a solution that is not involved another action button, I want the user to click only once

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible (at least not with native shiny code - you can always hack a workaround). An open issue for this exists on the shiny github repository: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1705

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accidentally found another workaround. If you use `tabsetPanel()` and place the more expensive calculation in a different `tabPanel()`, it actually presents it immediately... So if you don't have to have them both in the same page it can be useful

Comment: yes that'll work because shiny tries to optimize the calculations, and it only updates outputs that are currently visible to the user (which can be changed with `outputOptions` but that's a different story)